# Django South Foreign Keys referring to pks with Custom Fields

Tags: django, django-south

I'm working with a legacy database which uses the MySQL big int so I setup a simple custom model field to handle this:

```
class BigAutoField(models.AutoField):
    def get_internal_type(self):
        return "BigAutoField"

    def db_type(self):
        return 'bigint AUTO_INCREMENT' # Note this won't work with Oracle.
```

This works fine with django south for the id/pk fields (mysql desc "| id | bigint(20) | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |") but the ForeignKey fields in other models the referring fields are created as int(11) rather than bigint(20).

I assume I have to add an introspection rule to the BigAutoField but there doesn't seem to be a mention of this sort of rule in the documentation (http://south.aeracode.org/docs/customfields.html).

**Update:** Currently using Django 1.1.1 and South 0.6.2

**Update 2:**
Seems the Django code is responsible.

from django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey.db_type():

```
rel_field = self.rel.get_related_field()
if (isinstance(rel_field, AutoField) or
        (not connection.features.related_fields_match_type and
         isinstance(rel_field, (PositiveIntegerField,
                                PositiveSmallIntegerField)))):
    return IntegerField().db_type()
```

As I am overloading AutoField isinstance is returning True and it is defaulting to IntegerField. Guess I will have to copy the AutoField code and do it that way . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to copy AutoField when it's clearly FK's problem? Subclass ForeignKey and return correct type instead.

Comment: Yeah I discovered this after replacing all the AutoField code. ForeignKey then sets itself to bigint AUTO_INCREMENT which breaks things badly. Django 1.2 offers bigint so I am going to work around the problem with a manual migration sql query in my south migrations until we upgrade to 1.2 & 0.7.